# Problems with nested_form, model associations several levels deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, nested-forms

I'm having trouble creating a nested form that will work correctly with the following domain model using the `nested_form` and `simple_form` plugins. I think I'm constructing the forms incorrectly or the attr_accessible and the accepts_nested_attributes_for calls.

I have this domain model with the following associations:

company.rb

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :subscription

  attr_accessible :name, :subscription_attributes, :cycles_attributes, :payments_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :subscription
end
```

subscription.rb

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to: company
    has_many :cycles

    attr_accessible :company_id, :cycles_attributes, :payments_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cycles
end
```

cycle.rb

```
class Cycle < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subscription
    has_many :payments

    attr_accessible :payments_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments
end
```

payment.rb

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :cycle

end
```

my view is the following:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for company do |f| -%>
  <%= f.input :name %>

  <%= f.fields_for :subscription do |s| %>
  #assorted fields for subscription

    <%= s.fields_for :cycles do |c| %>
      #assorted fields for cycle
      <%= c.link_to_remove "[ - ] Erase Cycle"  %>

      <%= c.fields_for :payments do |p| %>
        #assorted fields for payments
        <%= p.link_to_remove "[ - ] Erase Payment"  %>
      <% end %>

      <%= c.link_to_add "[ + ] New Payment", :payments %>

    <% end %>
  <%=  s.link_to_add "[ + ] New Cycle", :cycles %>

<% end %>
```

the company controller:

```
def new
  @company = Company.new
  @company.build_subscription

  @categories = Category.find(:all)

  respond_with @company
end

def create
  @company = Company.new(params[:company])

  if @company.save 
    flash[:notice] = "Success"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error #{@company.errors.full_messages}"
  end

  respond_with @company
end
```

Of course, I'm simplifying the views and stuff, there are some validations and fields I'm not showing, but those aren't the problem.
When I submit the form I'm getting some weird errors, basically all info is passed in the params but it's not correctly nested :/

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"57wgXJinL6kql0F9CxShKpf11RhdMfqXnb6y8K/pDg0=", 
"company"=>{"name"=>"asdf12",
  "subscription_attributes"=>{
    "cycles_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{"plan_id"=>"1", "amount"=>"123", "months"=>"12", "_destroy"=>"false"}
    }, 
    "0"=>{
      "0"=>{
        "payments_attributes"=>{
          "new_1329843584974"=>{"payment_type"=>"Efectivo", "amount"=>"123", "receipt_number"=>"1231", "note"=>"asdf asdf", "_destroy"=>"false"
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, "commit"=>"Save"}

WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: 0
```

The error is:

```
@messages={:"subscription.cycles.subscription"=>["can't be blank"],
           :"subscription.cycles.payments"=>["can't be blank"]}
```

There is something going awry with how the attributes are being passed to the app, my guess is that when I click on the new payment button, it gets created "outside" the form... has anybody encountered something similar?

If you need any more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the nested_form plugin itself.

When having a has_one relationship and nested models as children of that, nested_form was having problems generating the forms.

I checked out this pull request and patched the corresponding file with the change

[Issue #124 in the nested_form repo](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/issues/124)

[the patch that fixes the issue](https://github.com/kevinrood/nested_form/commit/7fda6884cef3c64b17a5d0114e40f2518ce9eed9)

This code should be merged into the main repo eventually.